# iOS 9.1 beta 3-4 eating up my wifi downstream

Tags: ios

I just run into a strange issue. My iPhone 6 Plus 64GB (updated today to 9.1 beta 3) started eating my wifi downstream (not upstream) after I plugged it to my macbook for charging. I tried disabling any feature (I was aware of) that could download stuff in the background. Every app is updated on my device. There is also no indicator at the statusbar. Every app is terminated. When I unplug the device from charging and reenable the wifi connection the download process starts again.

Rebooting the device while unplugged does help but if I start charging the device it happens again.

Any suggestion what that could be, maybe I missed something here. The free space is gone from 6GB down to 3GB already.

Version: **9.1 (13B5130b)**

**UPDATE:**

Version: **9.1 (13B136)** behaves the same. I deleted almost all apps I don't use atm and searched trough every setting that could use background downloading. The device is downloading non stop (it should be 4-6GB already).

Comment: This is a beta expect bugs - report it to Apple as the NDA you agreed to says

Comment: @bmike updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

I would do three things to narrow down the culprit:

1. Connect to Xcode and look at the console logs for the phone - activity might be logged
2. Connect to [Instruments and profile the network activity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)
3. Connect to iTunes and make snapshots of the storage sizes (or use storage and usage on iOS) to see what bins are growing over time.

You can turn off iCloud to reduce many downloads, but it really depends on which apps you have installed, how they background data load and what data stores they are configured to pull. Since you are on the betas, you have many options to pick apart the data flow using diagnostic profiles provided by Apple and the developer tools similarly provided.

Comment: I'll try to profile the network activity as soon as I update to the latest Xcode beta. About the apps: none of them seems to grow at all. So strange.

Comment: @DevAndArtist I agree it's strange. I doubt it's app thinning, but that has been slightly problematic as the tooling is changing, the code singing is getting worked out and even your local Xcode can be pushing updates to your device using App Thinning. It's like debugging "enterprise software" all on your own Xcode/iOS fiefdom.

Comment: Downloading the latest Xcode right now. One thing I just noticed is that my iPhone redownloaded deleted apps. Also the AppStore app tries to indicated these apps with the (updates available) badge, but inside the update section of the store app there is no new updates available. Gosh this is so annoying. The device already downloaded up to 5-6 gigs behind the scenes.